# Show Filter Choices shows empty options in SharePoint 2010 List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, filter

We have SharePoint 2010 and there is a list that has 4600 items. When users try to filer a column, they get **Show Filter Choices** from the drop  down menu:

[image]

When they select **Show Filter Choices** They get a drop down menu above the column to filter, and it shows two options: **Empty** and **All**

[image]

How can we fix this, so that it would show the items instead of **Empty**

Comment: What type of field is it?

Comment: how many columns in the list and do have filter on any other column? clear all filters then try it.

Comment: The field is: Single line of text. We have another column (single line of text) in the same list  and it behaves the same way